# Clang-format and space between constructor initialization list and empty braces

Tags: c++, constructor, superclass, clang-format

Given this trivial C++ class definition:

```
class NotFound : public std::logic_error {
public:
    explicit NotFound(const char *s): std::logic_error(s){};
}
```

What option in [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) controls whether or not to insert a space between the call to the superclass constructor and the empty braces for the constructor definition?

Answer (score 0):

`SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: true`